# etl : can we aggregate dynamic number of rows and add datedynamic using-talend-open-studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, talend

I'm a beginner in Talend Open Studio, and I'm trying to do the transformation below.

From a SQL server fact_Table that contains:

```
id_facture  produit   mouvment    quantité_Stock    Date 
--------------------------------------------------------------
f1          p1        entrée      +50               28/04/2018
f2          p1        entrée      +10               01/05/2018
f3          p1        sortie      -20               02/05/2018
f3          p2        entrée      +4                02/05/2018
f4          p2        sortie      -1                03/05/2018
f4          p1         entrée     +2                03/05/2018
```

I want to produce this table:

```
id_facture  produit   mouvment    quantité_Stock  Date 
-----------------------------------------------------------
f1          p1        entrée      50             28/04/2018
f1          p1        aucune      50             29/04/2018
f1          p1        aucune      50             30/04/2018
f2          p1        entrée      60             01/05/2018
f3          p1        sortie      40             02/05/2018
f3          p2        entrée      4              02/05/2018
f4          p2        sortie      3              03/05/2018
f4          p1        entrée      42             03/05/2018
```

I thought of using tAggregateRow, but I didn't find it appropriate to my issue.how using a rolling sum or cumulative sum values group by column ?

Comment: To aggregate data in the way you need you can simply write proper t-sql query and put it into talend component tMSSqlRow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Talend` this should be accomplished at `Sql Server` itself and then you could just retrieve the data and work accordingly in your `Talend Studio`.

Your scenario is an example of finding the running total based on some id and date range. I have accomplished the to find the running total using `CROSS APPLY`, if you are using 2012+ version of `Sql` there would be lot more options for you. To find out the date range I have used `LEAD` which would identify the immediate next row based on the id.

The below query would do the work for you -

**Data Setup:**

```
create table #temp(id_facture nvarchar(100), produit nvarchar(100),  mouvment  nvarchar(100),  quantité_Stock  int,  stockDate date) 
insert into #temp
select 'f1',          'p1',        'entrée',      50,               '04/28/2018' union all
select 'f2',          'p1',        'entrée',      10,               '05/01/2018' union all
select 'f3',          'p1',        'sortie',      -20,               '05/02/2018' union all
select 'f3',          'p2',        'entrée',      4,                '05/02/2018' union all
select 'f4',          'p2',        'sortie',      -1,                '05/03/2018' union all
select 'f4',          'p1',        'entrée',     2,                '05/03/2018'
```

**Actual Code:**

```
;WITH CTE1 AS (select
T.id_facture, T.produit,T.mouvment,rt.runningTotal,T.stockDate
from #temp t
 cross apply (select sum(quantité_Stock) as runningTotal
                from #temp
                where produit = t.produit
                and stockDate <= t.stockDate
            ) as rt),
DateList (id_facture,produit,mouvment,runningTotal,stockDate,stockDateEnd)
AS (
SELECT id_facture,produit,mouvment,runningTotal
      , stockDate
      , LEAD(stockDate, 1) OVER ( PARTITION BY produit ORDER BY stockDate ) AS stockDateEnd
    FROM CTE1
UNION ALL
SELECT id_facture,produit,mouvment,runningTotal,DATEADD(DAY,1,stockDate),stockDateEnd FROM DateList
WHERE DATEADD(DAY,1,stockDate) < stockDateEnd
)
SELECT id_facture,produit,mouvment,runningTotal as quantité_Stock,stockDate FROM DateList ORDER BY produit,stockDate
```